# Certificate Management in Managed Kubernetes

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, azure-aks

We are trying to secure our AKS cluster by providing trusted CAs (ssl certs) to Kubernetes Control Plane.
The default API server certificate is issued by while the cluster is created.
Is there any way that we can embed trusted Certificates into the control plane before provisioning the cluster?

Like when we try to reach the kubernetes server it shows **ssl certificate issue**
To ged rid of this we must be able to add organizations certificates to the api server.
When we create a cluster in Cloud (managed Kubernetes Cluster) we do not have access to the control plane nodes, due to which we won't be able to configure the api server.

Could anyone please help me out figuring out how to add ssl certs to the control plane of kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

> When we create a cluster in Cloud (managed Kubernetes Cluster) we do
> not have access to the control plane nodes, due to which we won't be
> able to configure the api server.

And that's the biggest inconvenience and pain for everyone who likes anything else except OOB solutions...
My answer is NO. No, unfortunately you cant achieve this in case of AKS usage.

Btw, here also interesting info: [Self signed certificates used on management API](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1239). Copy paste here for future references despite the fact that answer doesn't help you.

> You are correct that per the normal PKI specification dictates use of
> non self signed certificates for SSL transport. However, the reason we
> do not currently support fully signed certificates is:
>
> 1. Kubernetes requires the ability to self generate and sign certificates Users injecting their own CA is known to be error prone
>    in Kubernetes as a whole
> 2. We are aware of the desire to move away from self signed certificates,
>    however this requires work in upstream to make this much more likely
>    to succeed. The official documentation explains a lot of this as well
>    as the requirements well:
>
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/certificates/
>
> Additionally, this post goes in deeper to the issues around cert
> management:
>
> https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/08/05/how-kubernetes-certificates-work/